# Calculus compute the value

Tags: calculus

Exercise 3 Consider the sequence, with $n\in\mathbb{N}$, defined by:

$$
I_{n}=\int_{0}^{1}x^{n}\tan x\,dx.
$$

Find $\theta\in\mathbb{R}$ such that

$$
\lim_{n\to\infty}n^{\theta}I_{n}\neq0\in\mathbb{R}.
$$

$$
\begin{aligned}
& \begin{aligned}
I_{n}=\int_0^1x^{n}\tan x\,dx
\end{aligned}\\
& \text{Use integration by parts:    }\int u\,dv=uv-\int v\,du\\
& u=x^{n},~dv=\tan x\,dx\\
& du=nx^{n-1}dx,v=-\ln|\cos x|\\
I_{r} & =-x^{n}\ln|\cos x|\bigg|_0^1+\int_0^1nx^{n-1}\ln|\cos x|dx\\
& =-\ln|\cos1|+\int_0^1nx^{n-1}\ln|\cos x|\,dx\text{\lparen since ln}|\cos0|=0)\\
& \text{Consider the limit:}\\
& \lim_{n\to\infty}n^{\theta}I_{r}\begin{aligned}=\lim_{n\to\infty}n^{\theta}\left(-\ln|\cos1|+\int_0^1nx^{n-1}\ln|\cos x|\,dx\right)\end{aligned}\\
& \text{Focus on the integral part:}\\
& \lim_{n\to\infty}n^{\theta}\int_0^1nx^{n-1}\ln|\cos x|\,dx
\end{aligned}
$$

I don't compute the $\theta$ value

Answer (score 1):

For large $n$, the integral $I_n = \int_0^1 x^n \tan x\, dx$ is dominated by values of the integrand near $x=1$. If we replace $\tan x$ in the integral with $\tan(1)$, we get
\begin{equation}
I_n \approx \int_0^1 x^n \tan(1)dx = \frac{\tan(1)}{n+1}
\end{equation}
for large $n$. Thus $\theta = 1$ is the only value that yields a nonzero *real* number for the limit $\lim_{n\rightarrow\infty} n^{\theta} I_n$.

Edit:

This can be made more rigorous by using Taylor's theorem with remainder, in which case $\tan x$ can be written as
\begin{equation}
\tan x \;=\; \tan(1) - \sec^2(\xi)(1-x)\, ,
\end{equation}
where $\xi$ is a value between $1$ and $x$. On the interval $[0,1]$, $\sec^2(\xi)$ is bounded below by $1$ and above by $\sec^2(1)$. Therefore:
\begin{equation}
\tan(1) - \sec^2(1) (1-x) \;\leq\; \tan(x) \;\leq\; \tan(1) - (1-x)
\end{equation}
Inserting this into the expression for $I_n$ yields
\begin{equation}
\frac{\tan(1)}{n+1} \;-\; \frac{\sec^2(1)}{n^2 + 3n + 2} \;\leq\; I_n \;\leq\; \frac{\tan(1)}{n+1} \;-\; \frac{1}{n^2 + 3n + 2}
\end{equation}
This proves the contention that $\theta = 1$ is the only value that yields a nonzero, finite value for the limit.

Comment: Is there an easier way?I didn't understand ，sorry

Comment: For large $n$, the integrand $x^n\tan x$ is peaked strongly near $x=1$. As $n$ increases, more and more of the value of the integral comes from values of $x$ near $1$. Close to $x=1$, $\tan x$ is close to $\tan(1)$, so in the limit of large $n$ we approximate the integral by replacing $\tan x$ with $\tan(1)$. Then the integral can be done analytically to yield $I_n \approx \tan(1)/(n+1)$.

Comment: Sorry, I understand this step, but I don’t understand the following steps.

Comment: If $I_n$ looks like $\tan(1)/(n+1)$ for large $n$ then the limit $\lim_{n\rightarrow\infty}n^{\theta}I_n$ goes to zero if $\theta < 1$, diverges if $\theta > 1$, and goes to $\tan(1)$ for $\theta=1$. As for the rest, see [the wikipedia article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Taylor%27s_theorem#Explicit_formulas_for_the_remainder) on Taylor's theorem, especially the discussion of remainders.

Comment: I think it's should be greater than or equal to 1. The question does not say that divergence is not allowed.

Comment: It says the limit must be a real number. If it diverges, it doesn't go to a real number.

Answer (score 1):

Integrating by parts (but going in the other direction than you):
$$
I_n=\left[ \frac{x^{n+1}}{n+1}\tan x\right]_0^1-\int_0^1\frac{x^{n+1}}{n+1}(1+\tan^2 x)dx=\frac{\tan 1}{n+1}+J_n\tag{2}$$
and $$|J_n|\leq \frac {1+\tan^2 1} {n+1}\int_0^1x^{n+1}dx=\frac {1+\tan^2 1} {(n+1)(n+2)}\tag{2}$$
Combining $(1)$ and $(2)$ yields
$$\lim_{n\rightarrow+\infty}nI_n = \tan 1$$